# Creating a language on the Rubinius VM

Tags: vm-implementation, rubinius

I'm looking to play around with the Rubinius VM to create a langauage, but just reading the documentation, I'm still quite lost on how to get started. Even looking at [the projects](http://rubini.us/projects/), I still can't seem to figure out where the parsing and using the vm comes into place. Does anyone have any resources for this?

Answer (score 4):

Hey I'm a contributor to the Fancy language that runs on rubinius. If you're interested in parsing take a look at boot/rbx-compiler there you'll find a Parser (implemented with KPEG) that basically constructs a tree of AST nodes, each of those nodes has a bytecode method that produces the rubinius vm instructions for everything to work. Fancy share a lot of semantics with ruby, so I guess starting with it would be easy if you're already familiar with ruby. You'll just need to checkout the examples/ dir to geet a feeling on the language and then the kpeg parser, ast nodes, loader, as you progress exploring the compiler. These days Fancy is bootstrapped (that means that the compiler has been written in fancy itself - at lib/compiler) but rbx-compiler is the first step in that process.

Hope exploring Fancy's source code can be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you hadn't seen it, check out Evan's [keynote from 2011 LA Ruby Conf](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/489-larubyconf2011-keynote). He shows how to build a simple language, which might be helpful.